# I want clear a point about definitions.

Tags: logic

I want know wether "defnitions" are if and only if. For example if a set satsfies all four group axioms we say it is group but then we go other way also.

thank you.

Comment: Yes they are. Always.

Comment: Yes, $A$ "defined as" $B$ is equivalent to $A \Leftrightarrow B$.